# Select row with the earliest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a query in which I am returning multiple rows for a given event, for example:

```
ID      |   DateTime                | String

1017436 |   2013-09-13 05:19:20.000 |                 Hello 
1017436 |   2013-09-13 11:49:00.000 |                 World
```

I want the result to contain only the *earliest* occurrences of the row for any given ID, but am running into trouble.

I originally, thought a query like this would be the answer:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT *,
           rn =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ixBug ORDER BY dt)
    FROM dbo.BugEvent
) 
SELECT ixBug, dt, s
    FROM cte
    WHERE 
        ixBug IN (SELECT Bug.ixBug
                        FROM 
                            dbo.Bug
                                JOIN
                            dbo.Mailbox ON Mailbox.ixMailbox = Bug.ixMailbox
                        WHERE
                                ixBug = '1017436'
                                AND 
                                    YEAR(dtOpened) >= '2013'
                                AND
                                    MONTH(dtOpened) = '09'
                                AND
                                    sOriginalTitle NOT LIKE '\[web\]%' ESCAPE '\'
                                AND 
                                    dbo.Bug.ixProject = (SELECT ixProject
                                                            FROM dbo.Project
                                                            WHERE sProject = 'Support')
                                AND
                                    dbo.Bug.ixCategory = (SELECT ixCategory
                                                            FROM dbo.Category
                                                            WHERE sCategory = '.inquiry')               
                                AND
                                    Bug.ixBug NOT IN(SELECT Bug.ixBug
                                                    FROM 
                                                        dbo.Bug
                                                            JOIN
                                                        dbo.Mailbox ON Mailbox.ixMailbox = Bug.ixMailbox
                                                    WHERE 
                                                                YEAR(dtOpened) >= '2013'
                                                            AND
                                                                MONTH(dtOpened) <= '09'
                                                            AND
                                                                sOriginalTitle LIKE '\[web\]%' ESCAPE '\'
                                                            AND 
                                                                dbo.Bug.ixProject = (SELECT ixProject
                                                                                FROM dbo.Project
                                                                                WHERE sProject = 'Support')
                                                            AND
                                                                dbo.Bug.ixCategory = (SELECT ixCategory
                                                                                        FROM dbo.Category
                                                                                        WHERE sCategory = '.inquiry')))
        AND
            sVerb = 'Incoming Email';
```

But, for some reason the result keeps both rows.

Comment: All four answers are good but your question might be incomplete.  How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: The dates relate to when an email was sent, so are very unlikely to happen (one ID peer user).

Comment: If you want to select dates after a specific one, like on September 1, 2013 and afterwards, don't use `YEAR(dtOpened) >= '2013' AND MONTH(dtOpened) = '09'` as it makes any index useless. Use: `dtOpened >= '20130901'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions for this, either `ROW_NUMBER()` or `MIN()`. The idea is to partition the rows by the ID - `OVER (PARTITION BY id)` - and then either assign row numbers (ordered by the datetime) or find the minimum datetime per ID.

Solution with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT id, datetime, string,
           rn =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime)
    FROM tableX
  ) 
SELECT id, datetime, string
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 ;
```

and with `MIN()`:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT id, datetime, string,
           min_datetime =  MIN(datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
    FROM tableX
  ) 
SELECT id, datetime, string
FROM cte
WHERE datetime = min_datetime ;
```

The second version has slightly different behaviour. If there are two (or more) rows with exactly same datetime for an ID, they will be both in the result.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get it to work though, I updated the query with the actual query I've been using (which is pretty complex), but the result is still the same.

Comment: I see the `rn = ROW_NUMBER()...` in your query but I can't see the `WHERE rn = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which generates sequential number that you can filter with.

```
SELECT  ID, DateTime, String
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  ID, DateTime, String,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateTime) RN
            FROM    tableName
        ) a
WHERE   RN = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e59d9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Select the min date for each ID in a common table expression CTE, then join back to it.

```
with minDates (id, date)
as
(
     select id, min(date) as date from YourTable
     group by id

)

select yt.*
from YourTable yt
inner join minDates md on yt.id = md.id and yt.date = md.date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 id, date_time, string
from table
where id = ?
order by date_time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  ID
, DateTime
, String
From MyTable t1
Where t1.DateTime =
(
    Select Min(t2.DateTime)
    From MyTable t2
    Where td.ID = t1.ID
)
```

Use a subquery to get the min DateTime for each ID group, then use that to qualify which of the IDs you pull. In case of tie, though, you will get both. If the IDs are in time sequence, you could avoid this by using the ID rather than the DateTime as the selector.